# Scaling in matlab

Tags: matlab, fill

I am trying to get a square to scale from 100% down to 25% of its original size during an animation in matlab.  I am confused what scaling factor I should multiply it by so that this scaling would occur.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 25% area means 50% side lengths, so it depends what measurement you are controlling.

Comment: Misread.  I thought the OP wanted to scale a dimension and not the area of the square.  Oops!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean 25% of it's original side dimension, that you want the corner position to stay constant. May I suggest rectangle, instead of fill? If fill is necessary, I'll update my answer to reflect that.

```
scale = 0.25;
fill('Position',[x,y,scale*w,scale*h])
```

If any of these assumptions are invalid, just let me know and I'll edit the solution. Good luck!